# Functional code for finding index in array

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I would like to refactor this piece of *Scala* code in functional style:

```
var k = -1
for (i <- 0 until array.length)
  if ((i < array.length - 1) && array(i) < array(i + 1))
    k = i
```

Array in *Scala* has `indexWhere`, which can be used for something like `val index = array.indexWhere(c => c == 'a')`. I'm looking for something similar, which would take into account two sequential elements of array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you need to look at adjacent elements in a collection, the usual functional approach is to "zip" the collection with its tail. Consider the following simplified example:

```
scala> val xs = List(5, 4, 2, 3, 1)
xs: List[Int] = List(5, 4, 2, 3, 1)

scala> val tail = xs.tail
tail: List[Int] = List(4, 2, 3, 1)

scala> xs.zip(tail)
res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((5,4), (4,2), (2,3), (3,1)
```

Now we can use `indexWhere`:

```
scala> res0.indexWhere { case (x, y) => x < y }
res1: Int = 2
```

In your case, the following is essentially equivalent to your code:

```
val k = (array zip array.tail) lastIndexWhere { case (x, y) => x < y }
```

I'm using `lastIndexWhere` instead of `indexWhere`, since in your code you don't stop the loop when you hit a pair for which the predicate holds.

Answer (score 11):

`sliding` gives you sliding window into the collection, ie

```
scala> Array(1,2,2,4,5,6, 6).sliding(2).toList
res12: List[Array[Int]] = List(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(2, 4), Array(4, 5), Array(5, 6), Array(6, 6))
```

So that would make finding the index of the first matching pair easy:

```
Array(1,2,2,4,5,6, 6).sliding(2).indexWhere { case Array(x1, x2) => x1 == x2 }
```

That only gives you the first index, use `collect` to catch em all!

```
Array(1,2,2,4,5,6, 6)
  .sliding(2)     //splits each in to pairs
  .zipWithIndex   //attaches the current index to each pair
  .collect { case (Array(x1, x2), index) if (x1 == x2) => index }  //collect filters out non-matching pairs AND transforms them to just the inde
```

Comment: I know it's a matter of taste, but the fact that the `sliding` approach gives you collections of length two (instead of tuples) makes it feel clunky here to me. Also, many (most?) functional language don't provide a `sliding` function in their standard collections API, while `zip` is pretty universal.